# How to send the div's style through button's onclick in <aura:iteration>?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, css, lightning-design-system

Even the example from "Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide
" doesn't work. I can't set the style to my div. It's because of iteration. How can I fix that?

**cmp:**

```
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="obj">     
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutBigCardsColumn">
                <div class="slds-panel__body">
                    <p><b>{!obj.Name}</b></p>
                    <p>
                        <span class="spanButtonToResults">
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:chevrondown" onclick="{!c.show}" />
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p>{!obj.Location__c}</p>
                </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div aura:id="divId">
                        <p><b>Detailed INFO about {!obj.Name}</b></p>
                    </div>
            </lightning:layout>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:component>
```

**js:**

```
show : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("divId").set("v.class", "divShow");  //"component.find(...).set is not a function"
}

show : function(component, event, helper) {
    //It doesn't work too!
    var cmpTarget = component.find('divId');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'divShow');
}
```

**css:**

```
.THIS .divShow {
color: #66C2FF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

actually second `show` variant is working correctly. The only difference is that you have to correctly define class in your style. According to your component markup, `<div aura:id="divId">Hello!</div>` is top-level element. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm)

> The  element matches the .THIS.white selector and
>   renders with a white background. Note that there **is no space in the
>   selector** as this rule is for top-level elements.

so you want to have style:

```
.THIS.divShow {
    color: #66C2FF;
}
```

---

first variant `component.find("divId").set("v.class", "divShow");` is not working because you only can set attribute values for lightning components, that are accessible for current component. `div` is not lightning component.

---

assuming all above, you want to have the following:

**component.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <span class="spanButtonToResults">
        <lightning:buttonIcon name="action" iconName="utility:chevrondown" onclick="{!c.show2}" alternativeText="Action"/>
    </span>                 
    <div aura:id="divId">Hello!</div>
</aura:component>
```

**componentController.js**

```
({    
    show2 : function(component, event, helper) {
        var cmpTarget = component.find('divId');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'divShow');
    }
})
```

**component.css**

```
.THIS.divShow {
    color: #66C2FF;
}
```

everything is working :)

Comment: No. it's not a top element) Thank you. I already understood what kind of problem is here: both elements are in `<aura:iteration>`. And it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I updated it. Without iteration all is fine :(